# The thing that breaks whenever its name is called

Tags: riddle

This riddle has puzzled me:

> Name the thing that is so flimsy that it breaks even by saying its name.

I have gone through many things, but nothing fits this riddle. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is

> Silence

So flimsy that it breaks even by saying its name

> Once one utters the word "silence" one has broken any existing silence.

Comment: Well, Thanks. I do not know why I did not think of this.

Answer (score 7):

> Nothing

Just a random idea.

> When you say "Nothing", there is no longer nothing; there is now something (your voice). Just a random idea; inspired when you said "nothing fits to this riddle"

Comment: This guess is very close to the intended answer

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is:

> silence which is broken when you say 'silence'

Comment: The answer is already has already been posted. Do you have any other answer?